# React render string as HTML in ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I'm using ant design dropdown. I have dynamic data from API and when I try to render those data into [dropdown menu](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/), It is rending as string.

So I used this [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser) library to render string as HTML but it does not work.

```
renderSocialMedia = () => {
if (this.props.weblookup) {
  let socialmedialookup = this.props.weblookup
  webitems = ""
  return socialmedialookup.map((k, index) => {
    if (k.name.toLowerCase() != "other")
      return webitems = "<Menu.Item key=" + k.id + ">" + k.name + "</Menu.Item>"
  })
 }
}
```

> {ReactHtmlParser(webitems)}

```
<FormItem>
 {getFieldDecorator('AddNetwork', {
  initialValue: "",
 })(
 <Dropdown overlay={
  <Menu onClick='{this.handleMenuClick}'>
    <div>{ReactHtmlParser(webitems)}</div>
  </Menu>
} trigger={['click']}>
 <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
  Add Username 
  <Icon type="down" />
 </a>
</Dropdown>
)}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: try  return webitems = <Menu key={ k.id }>{ k.name}</Menu>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using React you must properly format a DOM element. So, Try this,

```
return webitems = <Menu.Item key={ k.id }>{ k.name}</Menu.Item>
```

Hope it helps. **Happy Coding**!!